# Error sending email using CDO on port 587 (TLS)

Tags: c++, email, cdo.message

Is there any trick to sending mail with CDO on port 587 (the port that uses TLS security protocol)?

This is my C++ code:

```cpp
CDO::IMessagePtr iMsg(__uuidof(CDO::Message));
CDO::IConfigurationPtr iConf = iMsg->GetConfiguration();
CDO::FieldsPtr iFields;
_bstr_t empty("");
iConf->Load(CDO::cdoIIS,empty);  // this string constant from import
iFields = iConf->Fields;

iFields->Item["https://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"]->Value = _variant_t(szServer);
iFields->Item["https://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"]->Value    = _variant_t(587);
iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"]->Value           = 2;
iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"]->Value = _variant_t(1); // Basic
iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"]->Value    = _variant_t(szUser);
iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"]->Value     = _variant_t(szPassword);

if(iUseSSLTLS == 2)
    iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls"]->Value = _variant_t(true);
else
    iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl"]->Value = _variant_t(true);

iFields->Update();
etc... etc...
```

If I use this code with `smtp.gmail.com`:

- server: smtp.gmail.com,
- port: 587,
- sndtls = true,
- account: my gmail account,
- password:

I obtain the following response:

- Code = 8004020e,
- Code meaning = Impossibile modificare o eliminare un oggetto che è stato aggiunto utilizzando COM+ Admin SDK,
- Source = (null),
- Description = Indirizzo del mittente respinto dal server. Risposta del server: 530 5.7.0 ***Must issue a STARTTLS command first***. y2sm3575389wme.12 - gsmtp,

(sorry ... part of the message is in Italian language, but take a look at the bold/italic one)

Obviously, if I configure Outlook 2010 using the same parameters, it works perfectly.

One more thing, if I use port 465 and SSL:

- server: smtp.gmail.com,
- port: 465,
- smtpusessl= true,
- account: my gmail account,
- password:

the code works fine, but I need to configure 587 port and TLS.

---

I eventually tried `smtpusessl` and `sendtls` together, setting them true:

```cpp
iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls"]->Value = _variant_t(true);
iFields->Item["https//schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl"]->Value = _variant_t(true);
```

And I obtain the following error:

- Code = 80040213
- Code meaning = IDispatch error #19
- Source = CDO.Message.1
- Description = The transport failed to connect to the server.

Comment: Pretty sure smtpusessl needs to be on for TLS as well

Comment: Do you meen;

iFields->Item[... /sendtls"]->Value = _variant_t(true);
iFields->Item[... /smtpusessl"]->Value = _variant_t(true);

togheter?

Comment: no, I tried smtpusessl and sendtls together, setting them true and I obtain the following error:

Code = 80040213
Code meaning = IDispatch error #19
Source = CDO.Message.1
Description = The transport failed to connect to the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CDO/SMTP/TLS in VB6 to send email smtp.office365.com mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530037/using-cdo-smtp-tls-in-vb6-to-send-email-smtp-office365-com-mail-server)

Answer (score 10):

After over 2 years, I found a solution, well ... not a solution, but now I know why it didn't work, e why it will never work. It seems there's a bug in CDO library: it can handle STARTTLS command on port 25, but it can't on port 587.

You can read more here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37d00342-e5e9-4c8d-975d-44362332d426/bug-in-cdomessage-smtpserverport-587-fails?forum=ITCG

As I've just written above, it's a bug and I think Microsoft will never correct it. The recommendation for the future is to abandon CDO and use "Power shell" or third-party components.

Comment: unfortunately the link is no longer valid: now refert to https://web.archive.org/web/20201022185758/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37d00342-e5e9-4c8d-975d-44362332d426/bug-in-cdomessage-smtpserverport-587-fails?forum=ITCG